# Using CSS to change text when Radiobutton is clicked

Tags: html, css, frontend, radio-button

I have this slight problem which I am unable to fix. I want the text displayed all the time and usually it should be bold with a font-weight of 700. But when either of the radio button is clicked, I want the font-weight to reduce and become 300.
How to make this work using only CSS and not JS?

My code is as follows:

```css
#content{
      color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.radio_item_menu:checked + #content {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="navbar_menu_store" id="input_description" class="radio_item_menu">
<label for="input_description" class="label_item_menu">Description</label>
<input type="radio" name="navbar_menu_store" id="input_shipping" class="radio_item_menu">
<label for="input_shipping" class="label_item_menu">Shipping</label>

<div id="content"><p class="testo_scheda">
This is some text</p>
</div>
```

I tried but it is not changing when I click on the radio buttons.
[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/smqxeLb4/)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `~` selector instead of the `+` selector:

```css
#content {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.radio_item_menu:checked~#content {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="navbar_menu_store" id="input_description" class="radio_item_menu">
<label for="input_description" class="label_item_menu">Description</label>
<input type="radio" name="navbar_menu_store" id="input_shipping" class="radio_item_menu">
<label for="input_shipping" class="label_item_menu">Shipping</label>

<div id="content">
  <p class="testo_scheda">
    This is some text</p>
</div>
```

The `~` selector selects a **general** sibling element, while the `+` selector selects the **adjacent** sibling element which `#content` is not.

You can read more about CSS selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) and [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048).